# Creating a Vector of Annual Revenue for Multiple Companies in R using Quantmod

Tags: r, dataframe, quantmod

I am trying to create a vector that will list the most recent annual revenue figure for multiple companies with data scraped using quantmod. My end goal is to have a data frame that will list each ticker in the first column and the corresponding annual revenue figure in the second column. My plan is to create the data frame using:

```
data.frame(tickers.list, revenue)
```

I currently have the script written to pull the financial statements for each ticker, but am not sure how to create the vector that will contain the revenue figure for each ticker.

Here is what I currently have:

```
tickers.list <- c("AAPL", "FB", "F")
tickers.statements.function <- function (tickers.list) {
  getFin(tickers.list, source = "yahoo", auto.assign = "FALSE")
}
fin.f <- lapply(tickers.list, tickers.statements.function)
```

Is there a loop I can use to create the vector that pulls the revenue figures for all tickers?

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Here is a solution I found so far - is there a more elegant way of accomplishing this?

```
#Creating Ticker List
tickers.list <- c("AAPL", "FB", "F")

#Getting Financial Statements
tickers <-  new.env()
lapply(tickers.list, getFinancials,env=tickers)

#Current-Year Revenue Vector
CY.revenue.list <- eapply(tickers, function(x) 
  x$IS$A["Revenue", 1])
CY.revenue.vector <- unlist(CY.revenue.list, use.names = TRUE)

#1-Year Prior Revenue Vector
PY1.revenue.list <- eapply(tickers, function(x) 
  x$IS$A["Revenue", 2])
PY1.revenue.vector <- unlist(PY1.revenue.list, use.names = TRUE)

#2-Year Prior  Revenue Vector
PY2.revenue.list <- eapply(tickers, function(x) 
  x$IS$A["Revenue", 3])
PY2.revenue.vector <- unlist(PY2.revenue.list, use.names = TRUE)

#3-Year Prior  Revenue Vector
PY3.revenue.list <- eapply(tickers, function(x) 
  x$IS$A["Revenue", 4])
PY3.revenue.vector <- unlist(PY3.revenue.list, use.names = TRUE)

#Creating Data Frame
fin.data <- data.frame(tickers.list, CY.revenue.vector,
                      + PY1.revenue.vector, PY2.revenue.vector,
                      + PY3.revenue.vector)
print(fin.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply` to extract the revenues:

```
revenues <- as.data.frame(sapply(1:length(tickers.list),function(x) as.data.frame(fin.f[[x]][[1]][1]) %>% .[1,]))
revenues <- as.data.frame(t(do.call(rbind,revenues)))
names(revenues) <- tickers.list
revenues
              AAPL   FB     F
Q.2017.07.01 45408 9321 39853
Q.2017.04.01 52896 8032 39146
Q.2016.12.31 78351 8809 38654
Q.2016.09.24 46852 7011 35943
Q.2016.06.25 42358 6436 39485
```